# netbeans install drupal plugin failed

Tags: drupal, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to install Drupal plugins in netbeans 6.9.1, but I get this message about a requested in version >= 1.29.2.8. (release version 1) but only 2.5.10.2 (of release version different from 1) was found.

what shall i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Netbeans 6.9 And The Drupal Plugin](http://www.hollyit.net/blog/netbeans-69-and-drupal-plugin) - for drupal 6, successfully installed on my nb 6.9.1
[Drupal Netbeans Plugin Rebuilt Against Version 7](http://www.hollyit.net/blog/drupal-netbeans-plugin-rebuilt-against-version-7) = for drupal 7, i didn't test it yet.